# Workaround for MATLAB's cell2table in OCTAVE version 6.2.0 or higher?

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to know a workaround for MATLAB's `cell2table` in OCTAVE. Any help this regard is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: “A workaround”? What are you trying to accomplish? Octave doesn’t have a `table` type, so anything related to tables will not work in Octave. A solution is to implement your own tables, or to rewrite your code to not use tables. There’s no simple solution.

Comment: Octave has table. It is part of the package [tablicious](https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/tablicious).

Comment: Note for future visitors: Tablicious is a third-party "community" package for Octave and, while I think it's a decent `table` implementation, it is by no means complete. YMMV.